# SpringDataJPA: How can i query an entity from its field which is a list

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity called MatchStats and I want to retrieve a list of matchstats where out of the list of Punters there is a punter with a username of "somthing"/punter.player.userName= "something". This are the three entities below that make up the matchstats

```
   public class MatchStats extends DefaultEntity {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Punter> punters;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Punter> winners;

    private double winning_amount; 

}
```

THE PUNTER ENTITY

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "Punter")
public class Punter extends DefaultEntity {


    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="player")
    private User player;

    @NotBlank
    private double risk;

}
```

THE USER ENTITY

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends DefaultEntity {


    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    @NotNull(message = "Enter a FirstName")
    private String firstName;


    @Column(name = "LastName")
    @NotBlank(message = "Enter a LastName")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(unique = true,name = "UserName")
    @NotBlank(message = "Enter a UserName")
    private String userName;
}
```

I expected springJpa to have somthing like this

```
Page<MatchStats> getAllByPuntersPlayer(User user, Pageable pageable);
```

but I don't think it is possible, is there a way I can achieve this ?

Comment: doesn't  `Page<MatchStats> findByPuntersPlayer(User user, Pageable pageable);` work?

Comment: @DirkDeyne it doesnt

Comment: are you getting a error - message? you could get a `org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags` when using multiple `List`s in a `Entity`

Comment: no, it actually works but not how i want, a punter class has a user and a risk field,  searching based on punter means i want to get all matches  based on the player and risk, and this gives me only one match, because a punter can only be attached to one match, but i want to get all matches by only the Punter.player (a player which is a User entity can have many Punters), it is a betting site,  The Punter Entity is the object that  the User and the amount he wants to bet, anytime he plays a match

Comment: Then please update the question. It currently asks something completely different which was properly answered by @DirkDeyne in the comment.